# Sending JSON from Javascript to PHP and getting nothing when I read the nodes

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am sending the following JSON string object from Javascript to PHP (do not worry, all data is fake).

```
{"paymentData":{"version":"EC_v3","data":"q3U0CWKXwy9TvFzLTtka/o1oNFJFIIt4VochiNobtCWfXeTtcNAzeAqpUh6pQRumc3CX44AGtxGo9EUV/4tD35YpSSeQCr2+x58OyKtJUeJkbBUYNkfM0ycpyBI+jwLG29f9Nk5n+VC0pDkkTzhg5tZUPRRjo2O1JeqJwhUXQGmpZdtsBt9ZRY+h4KzDRe7fZhWVJlm1oRoXd45MnYXb3SEXH/MvcJUdsTQNwX2rQ9j2IQJajYrchU0/Dx1W0laPt6DKf8xbWkxivuTZGqbnLEaXpA8XbBwTSECmn4IxMcXZKf1RumlEse89JmznAQq4NgeubLAp6rWae0V7hyIjJz4zU7P2eXQbBio+zrQK8mDq+c4OZbjSGLSSGM9PZbZmmReTs3rzqg48FczP","signature":"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","header":{"ephemeralPublicKey":"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE2mh3bkVPgDkm8mT8p6trU5Tr6Pjf6r+GeQRcDqQQ+eh00HtOsQHuKaL9m3qrbU7A==","publicKeyHash":IFe5oX+UZrULsh3Rb7XzIjR9k=","transactionId":"d79cbeea21aa72d275c629b34bac53769c9a0773f"}},"paymentMethod":{"displayName":"AmEx 1362","network":"AmEx","type":"credit"},"tid":"D79CBEEA21AA1FFEACA43F72D275C629B34BAC53769C9A0773F"}
```

on PHP I have:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file("php://input");    
$transactionIdentifier = (string) $data->tid;
file_put_contents("log.txt", $transactionIdentifier);
```

every node I try to extract, like `$json->paymentMethod->displayName`, `$json->paymentData->signature`, etc., is empty, but if I do

```
file_put_contents("log.txt", $data);
```

the whole string received is correctly dumped to the log.

why?

Comment: You try to decode JSON data with an XML tool. `json_decode` will do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name implies, `simplexml_load_file` is for loading XML from a file. The data you have here is encoded as JSON, not XML.

Try using `json_decode` instead.

Also note that you're missing the beginning `"` for the `publicKeyHash` value.

Answer (score 1):

use `json_decode()` in PHP.
`simplexml_load_file` is for XML not for JSON